# On clicking download button pdf need to 'fit to page' on browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, pdf

Currently, I have the code

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"  href="brochure/brr.pdf>Download Brochure</a>
```

On clicking the link it should show the pdf. 
But when it redirect to new page it became `fit to width`(full screen) how can I convert it to `fit to page` by default

---

**Current screen:**

[image]

---

**Expeccted result:**

[image]

Comment: It's browser default settings, you can't force settings clicking on link...

Comment: your question, it's not clear enough to understand. it's that all the code you have?

Comment: @Justinas but I have seen some pdf that is open in that manner that's why I asked

Comment: @Obink My question is I have a download button for a pdf file and when I click that button it opens pdf in browser window and the pdf is showing fullscreen means in full width, I need that on fit to page style

Comment: IIRC that's an option when saving in PDF format, nothing to do with the browser or the code. [edit] http://blog.gilbertconsulting.com/2009/08/how-to-force-pdf-to-open-at-particular.html

Comment: @ThePeach i have created the pdf using photoshop. can i make IIRC with photoshop

Comment: @GokulPP, I don't have PhotoShop, but I think you would need software that allows you to edit that property (very likely Adobe PDF Editor of some sort).

Comment: @ThePeach thank you